# Show that the function $f: \mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is not surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having trouble showing that the function $f: \mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is not surjective. I suppose that I have to show is that $\exists g\in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N},\forall n\in\mathbb{N},g\neq g(n)$. However, I can't think of a way to show that $g\neq g(n)$. I know that I am supposed to use the Cantor's diagonal argument. Could you give me a hint towards the proof?

Comment: There is no surjective map from any set to it's power set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick in the diagonal argument is to make sure $g$ is different from each of the $f(n)$s by constructing it such that $g(n)\ne (f(n))(n)$. Since this is the only constraint on $g(n)$ it is very easy to find a possible $g(n)$ that does *not* equal $f(n)(n)$ ...

Comment: This is what I came up with: Consider $g\in X^\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall q\in X^\mathbb{N}, \forall n\in\mathbb{N},n\in im(g)\Longrightarrow n\notin im(q)$. Therefore $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, g\notin im(f(n))$ and hence $f$ is not surjective. Does this suffice?

Comment: @Bright: No, that doesn't work -- there is no such $g$, because the image of $g$ must contain at least one $n$, and that $n$ is also in the image of $q$ when $q=g$. (Do you think there is something wrong with the approach I sketch in the answer, since you're not following it?)

Comment: What is the trick in constructing $g(n)$ then? My approach was to find an element in $X^\mathbb{N}$ using the diagonal argument and show that $f$ doesn't map to it.

Comment: @Bright: My proposal is to select $g(n)$ to be an element of $\{0,1\}$ that is not equal to $f(n)(n)$. There is always exactly one element of $\{0,1\}$ that has this property. This **is** the diagonal argument.

Comment: So the implication will be that $g\neq f(n)$ and hence $f$ is not surjective? This seems almost too simple.

Comment: @Bright: The implication is that _for each $n$_, $g$ is different from $f(n)$ and therefore $g$ is not in the image of $f$, yes. It doesn't need to be more complex than that.

Comment: I have defined $g=\{(n,x) : n\in\mathbb{N}\land \forall n\in\mathbb{N},x\neq f(n)(n)\}$ then since $|X|\geq2$ we can always find such an $g$. I didnt realize it at first that $f(n)(n)$ produces the sought "diagonal". But after I realised this, the proof became easy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Bright: In your formula, "$\forall n\in\mathbb N$" should not be there. Is it easy to come up with an $f$ such that, say, $f(5)(5)=0$ and $f(19)(19)=1$, and then there is _no_ $x\in\{0,1\}$ that satisfies $\forall n\in \mathbb N: x\ne f(n)(n)$, and therefore your $g$ becomes the empty set, which is not in $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$.

Comment: Should it just be $x\neq f(n)(n)$ then?

Comment: @Bright: Yes, that will work in this particular case because your $X$ has exactly two elements. In general, though, it is a somewhat strange way to define a function -- you're taking my hint very literally, but I'm sure whoever marks your homework would like more to see a more concrete way to specify the value of $g(n)$, other than "map $n$ to _everything_ that is not $f(n)(n)$ and hope there are exactly one of those" ...

Comment: Well I could say that in case there are more of those, one should take whichever. Either way, I am not sure of what you're hinting at.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is surjective, then $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is countable: $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,....\}$ and we can assume that $a_j \ne a_k$ for $j \ne k$.

Are you now in a position to use Cantor's diagonal argument to get a contradiction ?

Comment: There's no need to assume that the $a_n$s are distinct. And I'm not really seeing how it helps to write $a_n$ instead of $f(n)$; that's just notation.

Comment: This does just look like a way of restating the question to me.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f: \mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is a mapping.

On $\{0,1\}$ we have the operation of addition modulo $2$, so $0+0 = 1+1= 0$ and $0+1 = 1+0 = 1$, which makes it into a field, for convenience.

Define $h \in \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ by $h(n) = F(n)(n)+1$. As $F$ is given, this is a well-defined function on $\mathbb{N}$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Suppose there were some $m \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $F(m) = h$. This means that the two functions $F(m)$ and $h$ have the same values for all $n$, and in particular for $n=m$. But this would give: $F(m)(m) = h(m)$ while by definition $h(m) = F(m)(m)+1$. (!) This contradiction shows that no such $m$ can exist, so 
$h \notin F[\mathbb{N}]$ and $F$ is not surjective.